# Is there a way to monitor a page 24/7 and when there is an update, load the new content

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to load/check the new content that has been loaded to a section of a page. Some pages update all the time, but the section that I want updates only once in couple hours or minute. Although, no one knows when there will be the new content uploaded to that section. This can happen 24/7. What I want to accomplish is whenever there is a new content upload to that section, do something immediately(in this case, go into the link and load the page). The only thing I can think of as of now is checking that section of the page as frequent as possible, ie. every 30 seconds, every minute. However, there are thousands of pages(~6000 roughly) that I want to check on. I don't think this is an ideal way to do, let alone if that's possible for the frequency I want.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it without asking my bot to scrape every single minute for each page?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no magic spell here.  Web pages do not have a "notification" option.  If you want the info, you'll need to poll for the info.  Yes, it's going to be wasteful, which is why you should ask yourself why you are doing this.

Comment: This is basically right, but the job might be improved a bit by using caching, to at least avoid downloading the page if no part of it has been updated. There seems to be a `scrapy` extension [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/extensions/httpcache.html) that uses the If-Modified-Since header to only download if some part of the page has been updated.